# SQL update with PL/sql function

Tags: sql, function, plsql, calculated-field

I have to update  one column in my table ( the requirement to use function). I have created  simple function  for customer1 table. So how I can update my table using function .   Is  there any  ways ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_easy (name_in in customer1.last_name%type)          
   RETURN customer1.first_name%type IS
   name_tab customer1.first_name%type;
        BEGIN
  select first_name  into name_tab  from  customer1
  where last_name  = name_in;
     RETURN name_tab;
  END fn_easy;

 update customer1
 set first_name  = fn_easy(customer1.last_name);
```

I understand that we need to loop argument in function. The only one idea which I have is to  do it through the cursor.  But I don't think it is optimal to use cursor  for this task when I have 200 records.

Comment: Where are you using the function from? When called from a SELECT, you cannot use DML/DDL operations in the function. Similarly, when called from UPDATE/DELETE, the function cannot SELECT or execute DML on the same table. Seems like a PROCEDURE would be better suited for what you're doing.

Comment: Your example doesn't make any sense: the table will be the same at the end of the exercise as it was at the start.  So it's pretty hard to understand what you are driving at.  If you want us to help you need to provide a meaningful problem.

Comment: Your function is also going to error out the first time you use, say, "Smith" and there is a "Joe Smith" and a "Jane Smith" in the table. Anyway, under what conditions are you going to have a last name without also a first name?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is generally ok, but you have to ensure the select inside returns exactly 1 value, otherwise you will get an exception. If you want to select all values into an array, use `BULK COLLECT INTO`. To update a column value using a function, the column value type must be compatible with function return type.